# Barplot Multiple Variable (using ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a barplot with 2 variables.

I have a variable called "sexe" and the second is called "surchage_mentale". And i want this type of graph :

[image: The barplot I want]

But with yes : women/men, and no : women/men

```
df <- structure(list(sexe = c("women", "men", "women", "men", "women", "men", "women", "men"), surcharge_mentale = c("yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes")

sexe_surchargementale <- df %>% select(sexe, surcharge_mentale)

#first method
ggplot(sexe_surchargementale, aes(x = "surcharge_mentale", fill = "sexe")) +
    geom_bar(position = "dodge")

#second method
sexe_surchargementale %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "name", values_to = "response") %>%
  group_by(name, response) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = cnt, fill = response)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  labs(title="")
```

I put a sample of my Data. The first method doesn't work and I don't understand why, I'm complety lost.

Comment: Your data is fine, you do not need to "pivot" it. Also, you do not need quotation marks, try: `aes(x = surcharge_mentale, fill = sexe)` instead of `aes(x = "surcharge_mentale", fill = "sexe")`.

Comment: it doesn't  work I only have one bar called "surcharge_mentale" and fill it's just "sexe"

Comment: Are you sure you tried the command *without* the quotation marks? (`"`)

Answer (score 3):

No need to pivot here. Just use facets, and make sure your variable names are unquoted:

```r
ggplot(sexe_surchargementale, aes(x = surcharge_mentale)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", fill = "deepskyblue3", width = 0.6) +
  facet_grid(.~sexe, switch = "x") +
  theme_light() +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside",
        text = element_text(size = 14),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 16),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = "gray75", size = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "gray75", size = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]